# Expressing as a single logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms

I've got the equation:

$$\log_{10}(x^2 - 16) - 3\log_{10}(x + 4) + 2\log_{10} x$$

I'm looking to express this as a single logarithm.  I came up with

$$\log_{10}(x^2 - 16) - \log_{10}(x + 4)^3 + \log_{10} x^2$$

then

$$\log_{10} \left(\frac{x^2(x^2 - 16)}{(x + 4)^3}\right) $$
Please forgive me if I got the number of parentheses wrong.

This looks like the results of most of the examples, would you think further simplification is required?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Your instructor might wish you to observe that $x^2-16=(x-4)(x+4)$, which gives $\log_{10}\left(\frac{x^2(x-4)}{(x+4)^2}\right).$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is absolutely right! However, there is one final simplification you can make: to the fraction 
$$\frac{x^2(x^2 - 16)}{(x + 4)^3}$$
itself. Hint: Can you factor $x^2-16$?

Comment: Would it be correct to then say (x^2(x + 4)(x - 4))/(x + 4)^3

Comment: Yup! And after cancelling an $x+4$ from numerator and denominator, we get
$$\log_{10} \left(\frac{x^2(x - 4)}{(x + 4)^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean when you ask if further simplification is *required*, but it is possible. Your computations are correct; if you notice that
$$(x^2 - 16) = (x+4)(x-4),$$
then you can simplify your last expression,
$$\log_{10}\left(\frac{x^2(x^2 - 16)}{(x + 4)^3}\right),$$
to
$$\log_{10}\left(\frac{x^2(x - 4)}{(x + 4)^2}\right).$$
Not a major simplification, though.

Answer (score 0):

The given answers and hints suggest to cancel out the $x+4$ term that is

$$\log_{10}(x^2 - 16) - 3\log_{10}(x + 4) + 2\log_{10} x=\log_{10} \left(\frac{x^2(x^2 - 16)}{(x + 4)^3}\right)=\log_{10} \left(\frac{x^2(x - 4)}{(x + 4)^2}\right)$$

and this is fine.

But note that the equivalence works in this particular case because all the three expressions are defined for $x>4$, that is all three have the *same domain*.

This is not always the case, as for example

$$2\log_{10} x$$

defined for $x>0$ is not equivalent to

$$\log_{10} (x^2)$$

which is defined for any $x\neq 0$, for that reason we need to pay attention to the domain when we establish an equivalence between different expressions.

For instance, in the previous example we can say that $\log_{10} (x^2)$ with $x>0$ is equivalent to $2\log_{10} x$.